# two Constructor in one class?

Tags: c#

this is my code:

```
class sample
    {
        public string str1 = "";
        public string str2 = "";
        public sample()
        {
            sample smp = new sample("BB", "EE");
        }
        public sample(string s1, string s2)
        {
            this.str1 = s1;
            this.str2 = s2;
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            sample smpl = new sample();
            Console.WriteLine(smpl.str1);
            Console.WriteLine(smpl.str2);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

i assignd two string value to my variables but nothing occured .would you please tell me which problem ia have?

Comment: *"i assignd two string value to my variables but nothing occured"* **Something** occurred, even if it wasn't what you were expecting. Tell us what, so we can help you. (Separately: A *little* time spent catching the worst of the typos and such can go a long way...)

Comment: Please define "nothing occurred". Have you run this in the debugger to check what is actually being called?

Comment: I want to assign BB to str1 and EE to str2 but the value of str1 and str2 is still null

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to use `this("BB", "EE")` to call the other constructor. What you have done in your no-arguments constructor is create a *separate*, temporary instance assigned to a local `smp` variable, which has no effect on the `str1` or `str2` members of the object being constructed.

```
class sample
{
    public string str1 = "";
    public string str2 = "";
    public sample() : this("BB", "EE")
    {

    }
    public sample(string s1, string s2)
    {
        this.str1 = s1;
        this.str2 = s2;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        sample smpl = new sample();
        Console.WriteLine(smpl.str1);
        Console.WriteLine(smpl.str2);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: For example i have a Match match = Regex.Match(urlStr, "blah blah", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace); in first constructor and the match result e.g match.Group[1] must pass to second constructor.with your explaniation i cant do that

Comment: @BabakBst: This is a completely separate issue from what you described in your question. Please edit your question to reflect your **actual** requirements.

Answer (score 10):

You're declaring a `sample` object locally in your parameterless constructor. This is separate from `this`, the object you are actually constructing. When that constructor returns, `smp` is no longer in scope and will be garbage-collected, and in the meantime you haven't initialized your strings (as you noticed).

You have two options:

1. Just initialize the strings to their default values (Note that if you want common logic to occur in all constructors, the other option might be better)

   ```
   public sample()
   {
       this.str1 = "BB";
       this.str2 = "EE";
   }
   public sample(string s1, string s2)
   {
       this.str1 = s1;
       this.str2 = s2;
   }
   ```
2. Use the `this` keyword in the constructor declaration to refer to the other constructor

   ```
   public sample() : this("BB", "EE")
   {
       // no need to do anything else, but you can do other things if the situation warrants
   }
   public sample(string s1, string s2)
   {
       this.str1 = s1;
       this.str2 = s2;
   }
   ```

Comment: For example i have a  Match match = Regex.Match(urlStr, "blah blah", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace); in first constructor and the match result e.g match.Group[1] must pass to second constructor.with your explaniation i cant do that

Comment: @Babak Bst: There's no way to do that without a common initialization function, because alternate constructors MUST be invoked before any other calculations within the class (in non-static methods, of course) can occur. Simply have all your constructors call a common function that sets the appropriate fields.

Answer (score 5):

You're creating a new instance of `sample` in your parameterless construction. This gets discarded immediately after returning and does not influence the current instance of `sample` you're working with.

You might want to change it to:

```
public sample()
{
    this.str1 = "BB";
    this.str2 = "EE";    
}
```

Where `this.` can be omitted.

Another option, as others pointed out, would be to call the other constructur using:

```
public sample() 
    : this("BB", "EE")
{

}
```

Take a read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx).

Answer (score -4):

Your assigning local variable in the constructor, try this instead

```
this = new sample("BB", "EE");
```

Edit, as pointed out should be

```
this.str1 = "BB";
this.str2 = "EE";
```

Comment: You cannot reassign `this` inside a class.